# Coq MSet of bounded naturals

Tags: module, set, coq

I am trying to define a type for Set of natural numbers with given upper bound. Standard library's `MSet` seems to be a way to go. I found [this discussion](http://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/zptqoou2/how-to-use-msets#post2) which gives a nice example of how to define a Set of `nat`. However I do could not figure out how to extend it to subset  types. I tried something like this:

```
Module OWL.
  Parameter n : nat.
  Definition t := {i:nat | i<n}.
  Definition eq := @eq t.
  Instance eq_equiv : @Equivalence t eq := eq_equivalence.
  Definition lt (a b:t) := Peano.lt (proj1_sig a) (proj1_sig b).
  Instance lt_strorder : @StrictOrder t lt.
  ...
```

I will be working with sets with different upper bounds. But I do not see how to instantiate this Module with given 'n'. Ideally, I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
Module BoundedMNatSets := MakeWithLeibniz OWL.
Definition BoundedMNatSetN (n:nat) : Type := BoundedMNatSets n.
```

P.S. This question is probably rooted in my insufficient understanding of Coq module system, and not specific to Sets.

Comment: Does `Module OWL <: OrderedType.` help?

Comment: I think my problem not with ordering but with parametrization. I would like to have a set parametrized by `n`.

Comment: You will need to use a functor I'm afraid.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what application you have in mind, but did you consider type classes or canonical structures.

Comment: I will gladly consider type classes. What I need is fairly basic library supporting sets of bounded natural numbers. I will need to construct these sets, preferably using index functions and perform simple basic operations like set union, intersection, and difference. I looked at what math-classes have to offer but I have not figured how to apply these easily to bounded naturals. A small example would be greatly appreciated! Since I am already using math-classes it would be great to use it for sets also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a functor. Something like:

```
Require Import Orders.

Module Type FIXED_NAT.
    Parameter n : nat.
End FIXED_NAT.

Module OWL (N : FIXED_NAT) <: OrderedType.
    Definition t := {i:nat | i < N.n}.
    ...
End OWL.
```

You can then apply `OWL` to modules of signature `FIXED_NAT`.

```
Module N1 <: FIXED_NAT.
    Definition n := 10.
End N1.

Module OWL1 := OWL N1.

Require Import MSets.

Module M1 := Make OWL1.
```

EDIT:
What about:

```
Require Import Orders.
Require Import OrdersEx.
Require Import MSets.
Require Import Arith.

Module M := Make Nat_as_OT.

Definition has_upper_bound s n := M.For_all (ge n) s.

Definition t n := {s : M.t | has_upper_bound s n}.
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps a bit, but this is not exactly what I want to achieve. I would like to have `n` to be a parameter of type MNatSet, so I can use different sizes in different situations, without each time instantiating a module. For example using `Ensembles` I could do something like this:   
  Require Import Coq.Sets.Ensembles.
  Definition EFinNatSet (n:nat) : Type := Ensemble {x:nat | (x<n)}.
  Definition singleS (n:nat) (i:nat): EFinNatSet n := ....

Comment: I am playing with the last solution you suggested in the update. It looks interesting. I will update here once I will understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the suggested way may work for me. I have just a quick follow-up questions: 1) Why you chose `bool` instead of `prop`. 2) Why `fold` not `For_all` 3) How do I get additional lemmas such as in MSetFacts or MSetInterface for this set? Thanks! P.S. Here is a small example reworking your suggestion to Prop/Forall and trying to prove a simple lemma using it. http://ideone.com/gKcl6j Any comments are very welcome.

Comment: Really good questions ! 2) is because I did not know `for_all` and 1) is because I did not know `For_all`. I will update the answer. I am not sure if I understand 3). The basic answer would be to apply functors, such as `Module F := Facts M.`. If you want to import at the same time, you can do directly `Module Import F := Facts M.`.